# Y is a random variable with a N($\mu,\sigma ^2$) distribution.

Tags: probability

Y is a random variable with a N($\mu,\sigma ^2$) distribution.

Determine the lower bounds for the probabilities $P(|Y- \mu|<k\sigma)$, for $k= 1, 2, 3$ using Chebyshev's inequality and calculate the exact values. 


Using the Chebyshev's inequality for a Normal Distribution $P(|Y- \mu|<k\sigma)=P(\mu-k\sigma<|Y|<\mu + k\sigma)$, but then I don't know how to calculate the value that I need for the different $k$ values and also how to calcualte the exact values, can someone help me, maybe giving some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can help yourself by explicitly stating what the Chebychev inequality is and see what you need to plug in.

Comment: Yes but, I don't have the numerical $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the distribution, which values should I put inside?

Comment: If you're using a textbook, there should be a $Z$-table for the area under a standard Normal distribution. The probability for a shifted and scaled Normal is the same as that of $Z$, as in 

$$P\bigl( X - \mu > k \sigma \bigr) = P\bigl( \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > k \bigr) = P\bigl( Z > k\bigr)$$

The same goes for the lower tail.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, so I can calculate the Exact Values using the table, but what about the Chebyshev's values?

Comment: For Chebyshev bounds, I'm gonna repeat my first comment: explicitly write down the Chebyshev inequality (don't just stare at it), and see what is on the right hand side. You don't need to know the value of $\sigma$ and $\mu$. This will be my last comment here.

Comment: Yeah but you need the variance.. How can I compute it?

Comment: There are different ways to express the Chebyshev inequality. If what you're seeing has no $\sigma$ inside the probability parenthesis, something like $P(|X-\mu|>a) \leq \dfrac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$, then by taking $a = k \sigma$ one sees the $\sigma$ on the right hand side cancelled. How about you type up your version of Chebyshev inequality here and point to me why you think you need to know the value of $\sigma$?

Comment: This is what I have from the book $P(|Y-E[Y]|\geq a) \leq \frac{Var(Y)}{a^2} $, so instead of $a$ if I put $ k \cdot \sigma$, I don't need to compute the Variance, but my problem is how to calculate the numerical value, I still don't get it..